# Why my code using priority_queue cannot compile?

Tags: c++

Try to use priority_queue. The code is:

```
    struct HeapNode
    {
        int val;
        int row;
        int col;
        HeapNode(int a, int b, int c) : val(a), row(b), col(c) {}
    };

    class MyComparator
    {
     public:
        bool operator()(HeapNode &n1, HeapNode &n2)
        {
            return n1.val < n2.val;
        }
    };

    void myfunction()
    {

        std::priority_queue<HeapNode, std::vector<HeapNode>,  MyComparator> hp1;   //LINE1
        std::priority_queue<HeapNode, MyComparator> hp2; //LINE2
    }
```

Tried two ways as shown on LINE1 and LINE2.
Neither line can pass compilation.

Comment: You say "pass compilation" like it's a test. It's not, and it shouldn't be used as one. That aside, what errors does it give? Warnings? Those can be informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::priority_queue takes 3 arguments in constructor:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

In your case **LINE1** looks fine and should compile. What is the error message?

In **LINE2** you are trying to create std::priority_queue of custom type (HeapNode) with container "MyComparator" (not a container!).

> The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. The
>   container must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer.
>   Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual
>   semantics: front(), push_back(), pop_back(). The standard containers
>   std::vector and std::deque satisfy these requirements.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

"MyComparator" is not a Container and it doesn't support required methods.

I checked your code with **LINE2** commented out and it compiles. Have you included  and ? Do you have main function somewhere?

Comment: Error for LINE1: 'Error 2 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found'

Comment: 'Error 1 error LNK2005: "int __cdecl myfunction(class std::vector<class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >,class std::allocator<class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > > > &,int)" (?findKth2dArray@@YAHAAV?$vector@V?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@H@Z) already defined in mycode.obj
'

Comment: Make sure that you are including *.h files only once (read about include guards: [click](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Include_guard). What files do you have in your project? Are you sure your code is written in *.cpp file rather than *.h? Here you can check working example: http://cpp.sh/25qb